# store and fetch user-specific data for different users in mongodb and node.js

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, database-design

I am trying to make an application like instagram using node.js. The problem that I am facing is how to store the user specific data? I am a beginner in making these type of projects.

An user registers -> then logins -> then uploads picture.
I have a collection of `users` from where I do the Authentication. Now, I am stuck. I have thought of the way the application works but I am confused on how to get the images that a user uploads? I know how I store the images in a database but I don't know how to make them user specific.

In other words : Suppose `userA` uploads an image and `userB` uploads an image. How can I store them in a database? - Do I store them together and when one `userA` logs in I `GET` the images with his name or do I store those differently?

If I store all the images of all users at a single collection then it would be really slow if a huge number of images and users are there. I want to know about some method that will let me store the images uploaded by user at a specific contiguous memory , maybe or any other way.

Any Resource and help is appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to develop such an application, you should think about whether it would make more sense not to save the images in the database but in a file system.

In the database you then only save the path (perhaps in an array) to the respective images and possibly meta data of the images, such as the upload date. As a result, your database will not be that big, backups can be carried out faster and normal storage is usually cheaper than database storage.

Since is very easy to interact with the file system with nodejs , this would be a good solution.

Another option would be to use mongoDB GridFS. however, I don't know enough about it to explain this here.

I hope I could help you

Comment: Ok.. So something like cloud containers . I have read something like Azure cloud container.. Do you have any recommended resource to look into?